# Identifying root cause of "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform"

Tags: windows, powershell, mingw

I am working with some source code in C, which I compile using mingw compiler.
I can successfully compile exe but when I run it I got an error:

```
Program '<name>.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS 
platform.At line:
1 char:1
+ .\<name>.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ .\<name>.exe
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I want to get to root of the problem and understand what exactly is wrong with that executable? Is there any way to get more verbose info why Windows doesn't like it.

Comment: Could it be you compiled for 64-bit and the machine you are trying to run it on is a 32-bit OS ?

Comment: It can be a lot of things I believe. This is why I am interested to find more detailed error explanation if it is possible

Comment: If you just call ```<name>.exe``` on the command line rather than from a PowerShell console / script. does it work or give a similar error?

Comment: Try to open the .exe file with https://www.dependencywalker.com/
If somehow it is calling DLLs mixing 32-bit and 64-bit platforms it should tell you.

Comment: How did you run the application to get that kind of error message? Can you just try to run it from the Command Prompt and let us know what the error is you get?